# Demonstrative geometry around the world and its significance.

Tags: geometry, math-history, education

This is not exactly a mathematical question.

I am from Pakistan; and over here students are taught a subject 'demonstrative geometry' (as a part of mathematics) from secondary level education. Basically, we are given a theorem to prove and we have to make a diagram corresponding to it, and then prove it in two columns.

Firstly, I want to know if this is taught all over the world and if it is the same as Euclidean geometry?

Secondly, I never understood the importance of it. We never use any algebra; I do not understand if it can be used to solve practical problems. Is not then Cartesian geometry better?

Here, is en example:

[image: Sample theorem]

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but it sounds to me like you are describing a technique for structuring proofs, rather than a field of study.  In the US, we also teach the "two column" proof method as a way of organizing thoughts and encouraging students to justify their reasoning.  Geometry, especially Euclidean Geometry, lends itself to this because you can (sometimes) refer to a picture instead of a set of abstract axioms or theorems.  It is useful, or thought to be useful, because it helps improve analytic reasoning and discourages vague or imprecise logic.

Comment: Well, I have clarified my question a little. I want to know if it has any usefulness. Would not Cartesian geometry serve the same purpose and be more useful a the same time?

Comment: I do not see how this is an example of what you ask, since you state that "we have to make a diagram corresponding to it" but your example makes no sense unless the diagram is given with the question.

Comment: The utility seems to be as a method to teach students practical methods for proving theorems.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Not at all; you see Rory students over here are memorized 15 to 20 theorems; so when we see the question, we already know which corresponding diagram we have to make.

Comment: Thank you.  That's what I pictured.  Cartesian Geometry can be very useful, no question, but reducing everything to coordinates can quickly lead to unhelpful algebraic complexity. Sometimes purely geometric arguments can convey much greater intuition.